# Trimming audio returns empty files (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav, pydub

I'm trying to trim multiple .wav files considering different starting points (seconds), however the code I made returns only empty files.

Here is the code considering two files with two different starting points:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
```

```
path  = "PATH"
files = os.listdir(path)
```

```
#start of first song starts at 20 seconds;
#start of second song starts at 15 seconds
startSec = [20,15] 

endSec   = []

for s in startSec:
    endSec.append(s + 30) # adding thirty seconds
```

```
#Set duration in milliseconds
startTimes = [] 

for s in startSec:
    startTime = s*1000 
    startTimes.append(startTime) 

endTimes = []

for e in endSec:
    endTime = e*1000 
    endTimes.append(endTime)
```

```
for s, e in startTimes, endTimes:
    for f in files:
        song = AudioSegment.from_wav(path+'\\'+ f)
        extract = song[s:e]
        extract.export(f+'-extract.mp3', format="mp3")
```

Does anyone have any idea what mistake I might be making to have these empty files?

Note: this is my first experience with this library, so I don't know if this is the best tool or the best way to implement a solution

Another version:

```
for f in files:
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav(path+'\\'+ f)
    extract = song[startTime:endTime]
    extract.export(f+'-extract.mp3', format="mp3")
```

Changing the last loop, I got the two files, but both start according to the defined second starting point (15 seconds), instead of the first starting at 20 and the second at 15.

Comment: 1. pydub is using ffmpeg, so make sure you've got it installed right and that you are using the right version. 2. You don't really need to add 0*60*1000 in `startTime` or `endTime` to convert from seconds to mSeconds :)

Comment: Hi, @TDG. I have ffmpeg installed. I can trim a single file, but what I haven't been able to do is get the correct start for each one, when I consider multiple files. In another version, for example, I trimmed the two files, but only with the last starting point for both (15 seconds). I believe I'm making a mistake by passing the desired beginnings in extract = song[s:e].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the output of your last (outer) loop in the original version -

```
for s, e in startTimes, endTimes:
    print(s, e)
```

you'll see that the output is

20000 15000

50000 45000
so you get wrong start and end times.
The correct way to itetrate over the two lists is by using the [zip() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) -

```
for s, e in zip(startTimes, endTimes):
    print(s, e)
```

which yields:
20000 50000
15000 45000

So your loop should look like this -

```
for f, s, e in zip(files, startTimes, endTimes):
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav(path+'\\'+ f)
    extract = song[s:e]
    extract.export(f+'-extract.mp3', format="mp3")
```

Comment: Pls check my edited answer.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks!